# Xcode Cocos2D How To Add 50 Sprites With No Lag

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I need to add about 50 sprites to the screen then redraw them. When I try and add them like this:

```
[self addChild:Img];
```

This creates a lot of lag.

I have also tried creating a CCLayer then adding the all of the images to the layer but i get the same amount of lag. How can I add all of these sprites and decrease on lag? Most games probably have more then 50 sprites a page.

Comment: be more specific, provide details. Same texture 50 times ?  texture size ? on a device or simulator ? how do you 'measure' lag ? etc ...

Comment: in addition to YvesLeBorg questions where and when exactly do you try to create/add the sprites ?

Answer (score 1):

If all or most of your sprites are the same, then you could use one **CCSpriteBatchNode** for all CCSprites sharing the same texture or image.  This will save memory.

You would do something like the following,

1)define a CCSpriteBatchNode

2)add it as a subview.

3)define a frame from the batchNode

4)set it as displayFrame for the sprite

Answer (score 0):

Use the CCSpriteSheet, If you haven’t used sprite sheets yet, think of them as gigantic images that you put your sprites within. They come with a file that specifies the boundaries for each individual sprite so you can pull them out when you need them within the code.

The reason why these are such a good idea to use is because Cocos2D is optimized for them. If you use sprites within a sprite sheet properly, rather than making one OpenGL ES draw call per sprite it just makes one per sprite sheet.

In short – it’s faster, especially when you have a lot of sprites!